# problem with adding float values in mysql

Tags: mysql

there is a field MinimumTemperature,"float(3,2)" when trying to execute the request

```
insert into weather
(Address, DateTime,MinimumTemperature,MaximumTemperature,Temperature,DewPoint,RelativeHumidity,WindSpeed,WindGust,CloudCover,Latitude,Conditions)
values ('Washington,DC,USA', '2019-01-02', 43.2, 47.6,45.9,36.4,69.73, 6.9,3,98.9,38.8904,'Overcast');
```

Returns an error

> [22001][1264] Data truncation: Out of range value for column
> 'MinimumTemperature' at row 1

Comment: `FLOAT(3, 2)` means 3 total digits, with 2 digits after the decimal point. That only allows 1 digit before the decimal point, and 43.2 has 2 digits before the decimal.

Comment: Looks like you should use `FLOAT(3, 1)`